# jQuery sortable not working with multiple containers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make elements sortable but it just wont work for more then one container.
In the jsFiddle you will see that the first Container works but the second does not?

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed"
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; cursor:move; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
#sortable li.fixed{cursor:default; color:#959595; opacity:0.5;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmSgx/1867/

How to fix that? Im pretty new to this stuff and cant figure the soltuion for this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having multiple elements with the same `id` is considered invalid as an `id` must be **unique** for each element.

If you change your `id`s to classes:

`class="sortable"`

And change your jQuery to use the `class` selector instead of the `id` selector:

`$(".sortable")`

Your issue will be fixed, see working example below:

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
  cancel: ".fixed"
});
$(".sortable").disableSelection();
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
  cursor: move;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}

.sortable li.fixed {
  cursor: default;
  color: #959595;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery, jQuery UI + CSS links -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
  <hr/>
  <ul class="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default fixed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>

</div>
<!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
  <p>
    Enable a group of DOM elements to be sortable. Click on and drag an element to a new spot within the list, and the other items will adjust to fit. By default, sortable items share <code>draggable</code> properties.
  </p>
</div>
<!-- End demo-description -->
```

Or see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmSgx/1868/)

Comment: Brief look at all problems [related to *«duplicate id»*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate+id).

Comment: *«is considered invalid»* Moreover: the "id" concept, since years before electronics and coding, is a UNIQUE concept.

Comment: So Nick, your last edit doesn't bring any. *(You can revert some edits... The keyword is "roll back")*

Comment: lollll In [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53464324/revisions)